# if L operator on 2D space, then show the following

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

u_L = minimal polynomial

X_L = characteristic polynomial

lambda = eigenvalue

p_1 = poly (i think) that corresponds to the first companion matrix C_p1 in the block diagonal form as shown in image below

[image]